# loose keys after alter table set schema

Tags: postgresql, schema, alter-table, alembic

ran into a problem on PostgreSQL 12.5

```
ALTER TABLE old_shcema.my_table SET new_schema
```

first - everything is OK, everything is transferred except triggers, but if you try back

```
ALTER TABLE new_schema.my_table SET old_schema
```

then keys, foreign keys will be lost

what is the reason? Am I doing something wrong or is this a postgres bug?

Comment: 1) Define *... foreign keys will be lost* . 2) In `psql` does `show search_path` include he new and old schemas.  3) Where did you install Postgres from?  **Add answers as  update to question**.

Comment: this is Postgres.app 12.5 for mac os

Comment: show search path = public

Comment: You still have not defined what is lost/missing. Provide example of before and after. Do this **as update to question as text(not images)**.

Comment: hmm, I've looked around and it looks like a DataGrip bug that generates the wrong DLL.

When I read information about the table with "\d" it showed foreign keys.

However, in DataGrip they get lost for some reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't do it here (PostgreSQL v14).

```
richardh=> CREATE SCHEMA a;
CREATE SCHEMA
richardh=> CREATE SCHEMA b;
CREATE SCHEMA
richardh=> CREATE TABLE a.t1 (id int PRIMARY KEY);
CREATE TABLE
richardh=> CREATE TABLE a.t2 (idref int NOT NULL REFERENCES a.t1);
CREATE TABLE
richardh=> ALTER TABLE a.t1 SET SCHEMA b;
ALTER TABLE
richardh=> \d a.t2
                   Table "a.t2"
 Column |  Type   | Collation | Nullable | Default 
--------+---------+-----------+----------+---------
 idref  | integer |           | not null | 
Foreign-key constraints:
    "t2_idref_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (idref) REFERENCES b.t1(id)

richardh=> ALTER TABLE a.t1 SET SCHEMA a;
ERROR:  relation "a.t1" does not exist
richardh=> ALTER TABLE b.t1 SET SCHEMA a;
ALTER TABLE
richardh=> \d a.t2
                   Table "a.t2"
 Column |  Type   | Collation | Nullable | Default 
--------+---------+-----------+----------+---------
 idref  | integer |           | not null | 
Foreign-key constraints:
    "t2_idref_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (idref) REFERENCES a.t1(id)
```

Comment: i am using postgres 12.5
i repeated your steps and got the same error. FK are missing

Comment: Using Postgres 12.15 the above works for me. It would be good idea to upgrade to .15 as you are missing a lot of bug fixes, though I pretty sure your issue is not actually a bug.

Comment: i cant upgrade postgres, this is prod version

Comment: `12.5 --> 12.15` is minor update not a major upgrade. It represents 10 bug/security fix updates. Not updating is a bigger issue then leaving it as is.

Comment: yes, of course. i am agree with you. but version on prod is 12.7. forcing the business to update the database is a much more expensive solution than any other

Comment: Again it is a minor update not a major upgrade. You don't have to do dump/restore or pg_upgrade and Postgres is free. That being said testing on a dev database first is always a good idea.

Comment: thank you. I will raise the issue of updating.

though it's not about postgres.

when i repeated the steps in psql i saw. that the table does not change. All keys remain in place. Everything is fine.

This looks like a DataGrip bug from JetBrains.

After I move tables from one schema to another, and then back, it stops displaying keys and foreign keys